# Can I run aws cli once I ssh into AWS or: can ssh access give the same commands as AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Here is my issue: I am far more familiar with ssh than with the aws cli, so when I ssh into an instance I can run 'whoami' and any command that is, seeing how i am ec2-user with root (maybe?) level of access then can I do the same thing as I can with aws cli, such as: create-instance, stop-instances ?

Even something more perverted and quite useless maybe: can i run aws cli once I am logged in the ssh? And since I am logged is using secret/key needed?

Comment: also - what will happen if i simply type 'aws' in the ssh session? I should ssh to aws and type "aws" once logged in to see...maybe it will be seen as just a linux command?

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is a Python program that uses the AWS SDK for Python to make API calls to AWS. These calls require AWS credentials that are linked to an AWS account.

AWS CLI calls (and any calls to the AWS API) can be made from any computer on the Internet, including your own computer and Amazon EC2 instances. The one benefit that Amazon EC2 instances have is the ability to assign an **IAM Role** to the instance, which can automatically provide credentials. Any other computer needs to store credentials in a file, which will be used when making API calls.

So, your `aws` commands will work on an Amazon EC2 instance if:

- The AMI you select has the AWS CLI installed (all Amazon Linux AMIs have it installed)
- An IAM Role has been assigned to the instance

Please note that the credentials used by `ssh` to login to an instance (ssh keypairs) are **totally unrelated** to the credentials used to make API calls to AWS (Access Key/Secret Key).

Comment: thanks, so I just logged in via ssh, ran 'whoami'...got root - ok then I tried this: https://gist.github.com/kananlanginhooper/4e035d357d97c877448b - so are these secret/keys valid for 6 hours the one I need for the aws cli? and how to connect to my instance using this python aws program remotely? I trie typing 'aws'...got "command not found" while in ssh...strange maybe? I am on ubuntu instance.

Comment: It appears that the EC2 instance does not have the AWS CLI installed. You  should be able to install it with `pip install awscli`. The AWS CLI will automatically extract the keys from the IAM Role assigned to the instance, so you can just run the CLI commands without specifying credentials.

Comment: got it, now it seems pip isn't installed, like how is this even possible...I have python2.7 though - just verified, but no python 3? I mean i guess I should just create new instance maybe this one seems cut out...

Comment: If Ubuntu isn't a requirement, I would recommend Amazon Linux 2. It has everything installed.